# How to integrate this function? 5

Tags: probability, integration

The function is like this:

$f(x)={x^2}e^{-x}$

what I need to get is: $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$.

I know I should find a $g(x)$ that $g' (x)={x^2}e^{-x}$, it seems very hard because $(a(x)b(y))'=a'(x)b(y)+a(x)b'(y)$. So is there any solution about this please?

Comment: @T.Bongers I am sorry about that. I am new to this forum and I did't know the rules. I just forgot parts integration could solve this problem. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integral does not converge.

If you want a convergent integral, then you have to try with

$$\int_0^{+\infty} x^2 e^{-x}\ \text{d}x$$

**Just in case**

If the integration is the above one (mine, not yours) then you can obtain a result via by parts integration, calling

$$f = x^2 ~~~~~~~ g' = e^{-x}$$

hence

$$-x^2e^{-x}\bigg|_0^{+\infty} - \int_0^{+\infty}(2x) (-e^{-x})\ \text{d}x$$

The first part goes to zero, and you have then

$$2\int_0^{+\infty} x e^{-x}\ \text{d}x$$

Now you can integrate another time by parts, obtaining (with the same choice of functions)

$$2\left[-x e^{-x}\bigg|_0^{+\infty} - \int_0^{+\infty} -e^{-x}\ \text{d}x\right]$$

Again the first term goes to zero and you have simply

$$2\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x}\ \text{d}x = -2e^{-x}\bigg|_0^{+\infty} = 2$$

If you are familiar with Gamma function then you can obtain an answer **immediately** since by definition

$$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^{+\infty} t^{x-1} e^{-t}\ \text{d}t$$

And in this case $x = 3$ which mean you have

$$\Gamma(3) = 2$$

Otherwise, by parts always works.

Comment: Yes, there should be 0. then how can I get a function that g'(x) = ${x^2}e^{-x}$?

Comment: If the integral is $\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x} dx$, you simply have $\Gamma (3) = (3-1)! = 2! = 2.$

Comment: @YULiu I edited the answer so you can see the by parts method or the Gamma function method.

Comment: @DavidBowman Thank you very much. This helps a lot.

Comment: I learned calculus 5 years ago. Your answer reminds me to use part integration. Thank you so much. @DavidBowman

Comment: @YULiu No problem! Those types of integrals are very funny because you can solve them in a various amount of ways! By parts is surely the longest way, but it trains you.